# Doing a PCA using an optimization in Matlab

Tags: matlab, pca

I'd like to find the principal components of a data matrix X in Matlab by solving the optimization problem min||X-XBB'||, where the norm is the Frobenius norm, and B is an orthonormal matrix. I'm wondering if anyone could tell me how to do that. Ideally, I'd like to be able to do this using the optimization toolbox. I know how to find the principal components using other methods. My goal is to understand how to set up and solve an optimization problem which has a matrix as the answer. I'd very much appreciate any suggestions or comments.

Thanks!
MJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing about Optimization is that there are different methods to solve a problem, some of which can require extensive computation.

Your solution, given the constraints for B, is to use fmincon. Start by creating a file for the non-linear constraints:

```
function [c,ceq] = nonLinCon(x)
c = 0;
ceq = norm((x'*x - eye (size(x))),'fro'); %this checks to see if B is orthonormal.
```

then call the routine:

```
B = fmincon(@(B) norm(X - X*B*B','fro'),B0,[],[],[],[],[],[],@nonLinCon)
```

with B0 being a good guess on what the answer will be.

Also, you need to understand that this algorithms tries to find a local minimum, which may not be the solution you ultimately want. For instance:

```
X = randn(1,2)
fmincon(@(B) norm(X - X*B*B','fro'),rand(2),[],[],[],[],[],[],@nonLinCon)
ans =
    0.4904    0.8719
    0.8708   -0.4909
fmincon(@(B) norm(X - X*B*B','fro'),rand(2),[],[],[],[],[],[],@nonLinCon)
ans =
    0.9864   -0.1646
    0.1646    0.9864
```

So be careful, when using these methods, and try to select a good starting point

Comment: Thank you @Rasman. I was somewhat sloppy in my formulation of the problem. The unknown is the matrix B, with the constraint B'B = I, and the function to be minimized is f(B) = ||X - X*B*B'||. So, it's really a constrained optimization, with a nonlinear constraint. I'm wondering how that would be set up in Matlab. Also, looking at the documentation for the minimization routines, I couldn't find any mention of matrix responses. Where would be the best place for me to  read about that?  Many thanks again!

Comment: @user765195 ok, then you need to use fmincon. I'll edit my post to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

The Statistics toolbox has a built-in function '[princomp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/princomp.html)' that does PCA. If you want to learn (in general, without the optimization toolbox) how to create your own code to do PCA, [this site](http://www.nlpca.org/pca-principal-component-analysis-matlab.html) is a good resource.

Since you've specifically mentioned wanting to use the Optimization Toolbox and to set this up as an optimization problem, there is a very well-trusted 3rd-party package known as [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/) from Stanford University that can solve the optimization problem you are referring to [at this site](http://cvxr.com/cvx/examples/cvxbook/Ch08_geometric_probs/html/eucl_proj_cone2.html).

Comment: Thank you @kitchenette. This is very helpful information. As I mentioned in my question, I'm quite familiar with princomp and other standard methods to find the PCA. In fact, my question is not really about PCA as much as it is about how to set up and solve certain kinds of optimization problems in Matlab. The package CVX looks very promising, but I was hoping something either more low tech, or within the optimization toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the optimization toolbox? The documentation is really good, just try one of their examples: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/brg0p3g-1.html.

But in general the optimization function look like this:

```
[OptimizedMatrix, OptimizedObjectiveFunction] = optimize( (@MatrixToOptimize) MyObjectiveFunction(MatrixToOptimize), InitialConditionsMatrix, ...optional constraints and options... );
```

You must create MyObjectiveFunction() yourself, it must take the Matrix you want to optimize as an input and output a scalar value indicating the cost of the current input Matrix. Most of the optimizers will try to minimise this cost. Note that the cost must be a scalar.

fmincon() is a good place to start, once you are used to the toolbox you and if you can you should choose a more specific optimization algorithm for your problem.

To optimize a matrix rather than a vector, reshape the matrix to a vector, pass this vector to your objective function, and then reshape it back to the matrix within your objective function.

For example say you are trying to optimize the 3 x 3 matrix `M`. You have defined objective function `MyObjectiveFunction(InputVector)`. Pass M as a vector:

```
MyObjectiveFunction(M(:));
```

And within the MyObjectiveFunction you must reshape M (if necessary) to be a matrix again:

```
  function cost = MyObjectiveFunction(InputVector)
      InputMatrix = reshape(InputVector, [3 3]);

      %Code that performs matrix operations on InputMatrix to produce a scalar cost

      cost = %some scalar value
  end
```

Comment: Thank you @Dan for your response. I can't find anywhere in the documentation any reference to a matrix to be optimized. It's always a vector or a scalar. Where can I find some good reference about that? Thanks again!

Comment: More likely than not, you can just reshape your matrix to a vector, pass it to your objective function, and then reshape it to a matrix within the objective function. That should work for you. I'll edit and add an example.